# How can I retrieve data from firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

The image shows my firebase data.i need to fetch the yellow rounded data from the firebase. by using the entryId as key('BWO4D').

in above image shows my firebase data.data which have entry,lotid,entryid as my firebase child datas.
how can i fetch the yellow colored data from firebase using javascript.

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Try this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: yah.i checked  and i executed.but the code doesnt responding

Comment: var ref=firebase.database().ref().child('Entry/'+lotId+'/'+entryId+'/')
      $scope.vehicleDetails = $firebaseArray(ref);

Comment: can you please show all the relevant code in your question that you have tried?

Comment: $scope.vehicleDetails={};
        var lotId=$rootScope.loggedUser.lotId;
     var entryId='BWO4D';
     var ref=firebase.database().ref().child('Entry/'+lotId+'/'+entryId+'/')
     $scope.vehicleDetails = $firebaseArray(ref);

Comment: @AnjalyPv Please edit your question (there's a link under it) to include the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That also allows you to indent the code, so that it shows up with syntax highlighting.

Comment: var ref=firebase.database().ref().child('Entry/'+lotId+'/'+entryId+'/')
$scope.vehicleDetails = $firebaseArray(ref);

Comment: cant get value in firebase array.

Comment: This question really needs to be updated. Please include your code and firebase data as *TEXT* please, no images. Ensure the relevant information is in the *QUESTION*, not the comments as it's super hard to read. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

something like this. You get at the individual properties of BW14d just like any other JS object.

```
var db = firebase.database();
db.ref.child('entry').child('1').child('BWO4D').once('value').then(function(snap) {
    if (snap.val()) {
        console.log(snap.val().duration);
    }
    else {
        console.log('BWO4D not found');
    }
}, function(error) {
    // The Promise was rejected.
    console.log('mal-funk-shun');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var db = firebase.database().ref();

db.child('entry').child('1').child('BWO4D').once('value').then(function(snap) {
   if (snap.val()) {
       console.log(snap.val().duration);
}
else {
    console.log('BWO4D not found');
}
}, function(error) {
// The Promise was rejected.
console.log('mal-funk-shun');
});
```

See my jsfiddle sample. [Retrieving data from firebase](https://jsfiddle.net/vmk379rs/4/)